# R' Chanina B"T's strange behavior at his execution (Kalah 5, 4)

Tags: talmud-gemara, halacha-theory, tannaim

We all know the heroic story of R' Chanina Ben Tardion in its version in [Avodah Zarah 18b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Avodah_Zarah.18a.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) as he was wrapped in Sefer Torah and burned alive.

Interestingly, [Masechet Kalah 5, 4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Kallah.5.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (sorry couldn't find a decent translation) tells this story VERY differently, putting R"C in a questionable light:

> רבי חנינא בן תרדיון פעם אחת ... אמר אוי לי **שמא נתחייבתי מיתה לשמים**.  ‏

Notice, that R"C originally suspected that he was sentenced to death by the Heavenly court.

> עד שהיה יושב ותמיה בא קסטינר א״ל רבי גזרו עליך לכורכך ולשורפך בתורתך ולישראל עמך ועמד וכרכוהו בתורתו והקיפוהו חבילי זמורות.  ‏
>
> והצית בו האור **והיה אור מצטנן ומתרחק ממנו.**  ‏
> עמד קסטינר בבהלה א"ל רבי אתה הוא שגזרו לשורפך? א"ל הן.   ‏
> א״ל ולמה האור מתכבה? א״ל **נשבעתיו בשם קוני שלא יגע בי עד שאדע
>
> אם גזרו עלי מן השמים המתן לי שעה אחת ואודיעך**. ‏

Apparently **the fire could not touch R"C** as he swore it to hold on untill he'll be sure of the reason to put him to death.

> היה קסטינר יושב ותמיה אמר הללו שגוזרין מיתה וחיים לעצמן למה עול מלכות עליהן.  ‏
> א"ל **קום לך וכל מה שמלכות רוצה לעשות בי יעשה**.‏

And **the executioner let R"C go** and let him bear the consequences! Now is the interesting part:

> אמר לו ריקה, הסכימה עלי גזרה מן השמים **ואם אין אתה הורגני הרבה הורגים יש למקום** הרבה דובים ונמרים ואריות וזאבים והרבה נחשים ועקרבים שיפגעו בי אלא סוף שהמקום עתיד ליפרע דמי מידך. ‏

And R"C said, "if you don't kill me, there are many animals that will BUT you will be held responsible."

> וידע קסטינר שכך היא המדה מיד עמד ונפל על פניו וכיון אבד והשמיע קולו מן האש ואמר באשר תמותי אמות ושם אקבר באשר תחיה אחיה מיד יצתה בת קול ואמרה רבי חנינא בן תרדיון וקסטנירו מזומנין לחיי העולם הבא.‏

As you see, it says nothing about the negotiation on hastening the death or swearing to the executioner of letting him to the WTC.

As usual, I'm trying to put R"C's behavior into our Halachic perspective, raising some questions:

1. R"C was allowed, Wasn't R"C obligated to take the opportunity to go free when offered even if later G-d will find a different way to execute him?
2. If he could contain the fire, wasn't he obligated to delay his death by any means?
3. By breaking the swearing and letting the fire upon him, is it considered that he committed suicide?
4. If he was let to go free why he didn't remove the Torah scroll? (Frankly, we don't see that this passage mentions the Torah burned at all, so maybe he did remove, then it contradicts the whole point of the Gemmarah in AZ).
5. How come that the story is told so differently even factually?

Comment: Possible answer to #3 that the fate of all 10 martyrs had been decreed. Likewise Shaul Hamelech was informed by Shmuel that he and his sons would die in battle we find that he fell on his sword again one could ask did he commit suicide? I think in these cases they both died al kiddush Hashem.

Comment: @DanielRoss I agree as we don't know if it was done actively or passively, I just wondered if they had the ability to control circumstances, does it count as suicide if letting themselves die?